# How to display item info on selected item in RecyclerView using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

How to display some information from recyclerview selected item without using onClick method. When the app is started first item is selected and highlighted. I need to eg. use Toast with value of anything that is in data class. I have implemented onClick method but the question is how to do it without using this method.

This is MainActivity:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        val exampleList = generateDummyList(20)
        val exampleAdapter = ExampleAdapter(getItem, exampleList)

        exampleAdapter.onItemClick = { item, position: Int ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "Position: $position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
            val intent = Intent(this, ItemActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("itempos", position)
                putExtra("maxSize", maxS)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

This is adapter:

```
class ExampleAdapter(val chosen_item: Int, private val exampleList: List<ExampleItem>):
RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>()
{
    var onItemClick: ((ExampleItem, Int) -> Unit)? = null    
    var selected_item: Int = chosen_item
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExampleViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recy, parent, false)
        return ExampleViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExampleViewHolder, position: Int){
        val currentItem = exampleList[position]
        holder.tv_ID.text = currentItem.id.toString()
        holder.tv_NAME.text = currentItem.name
        holder.tv_EMAIL.text = currentItem.email
        if (position == selected_item){
            holder.tv_NAME.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)            
        } else {
            holder.tv_NAME.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)            
        } 
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return exampleList.size
    }
    inner class ExampleViewHolder(itemView:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val tv_ID: TextView = itemView.tv_ID
        val tv_NAME: TextView = itemView.tv_NAME
        val tv_EMAIL: TextView = itemView.tv_EMAIL
    init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                onItemClick?.invoke(exampleList[absoluteAdapterPosition], absoluteAdapterPosition)
                notifyItemChanged(selected_item)
                selected_item = absoluteAdapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(selected_item)                
            }            
            itemView.isSelected
        }
    }
}
```

I have second activity - when user click on item in first activity(recyclerview) - this second activity is open - then I raise the id of item by one and open again first activity where another item is highlighted. And I need to display eg. EMAIL from ExampleItem class.

This is second activity:

```
class ItemActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item)
        var itempos = intent.getIntExtra("itempos",0)
        val maxSize = intent.getIntExtra("maxSize",0)
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            if (itempos == maxSize){
                itempos = itempos
            } else {
                itempos = itempos + 1
            }
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("itemposplus", itempos)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to get the selected item at any time (without a click). There are several ways to do this. I recommend to you use **getAdapterPosition()** method in ViewHolder

First, save your ViewHolder

```
class ExampleAdapter(val chosen_item: Int, private val exampleList: List<ExampleItem>):
RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>()
{
    var onItemClick: ((ExampleItem, Int) -> Unit)? = null    
    var selected_item: Int = chosen_item
    lateinit var viewHolder: ExampleViewHolder

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExampleViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recy, parent, false)
        viewHolder = ExampleViewHolder(itemView)
        return viewHolder
    }
```

And then write a public method into the adapter for get the current item in activity

```
fun getCurrentItem(): ExampleItem = exampleList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition())
```

Finally you can get selected item in activity

```
val selectedItem = exampleAdapter.getCurrentItem()
```

Also you can check **getLayoutManager().findFirstVisibleItemPosition()** method in your RecyclerView

Comment: getAdapterPosition is deprecated - I am using absoluteAdapterPosition. But when I run the app, there is mistake lateinit property viewHolder has not been initialized.

Comment: Okay then try to move your code from onCreate to onStart or onResume.